# android - doInBackground return always false

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to shows a ProgressDialog while a list is loading data in an AsyncTask, but 'exito' in onPostExecute is never true, and the dialog never dismiss.
I tried to delete the `if (exito)` but the progressDialog dismiss and the list is charged a few seconds later, and it isn't I want. 
I want that progressDialog shows while is loading, and when is loaded, dismiss the progressDialog and change fragment.

Where is my mistake? Thanks

```
private class ATCargarProductos extends  AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{

        boolean terminado = false;
        Bundle bdl;
        FragmentTransaction transaction;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

        public ATCargarProductos(FragmentTransaction transaction){
            this.transaction = transaction;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (compruebaConexion()) {

                rellenaLista(new CallBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final ArrayList<Comida> listaComidas) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < listaComidas.size(); i++) {
                            ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails(listaComidas.get(i));
                            if (item_details.getTipo().equals("B")) {

                                results.add(item_details);
                            }
                        }

                        Fragment fragmentProductos = new FragmentProductos();
                        bdl = new Bundle(2);
                        bdl.putInt("tipoProducto", 1);
                        bdl.putParcelableArrayList("resultados", results);
                        fragmentProductos.setArguments(bdl);

                        completado = true;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFail(String msg) {

                    }
                });

                return completado;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando lista...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean exito) {
            super.onPostExecute(exito);
            if (exito) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `compruebaConexion` ever true? Is an exception being thrown that prevents `completado` from being set to true? (put a try/catch in onSuccess).

Comment: Yes, it's true. This method only check if you have access to Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rellenaLista()` is asynchronous.

Since it's running on a different thread,  `return completado;` is executed before you reach `onSuccess()`, and therefore `completado` is still `false`.

You don't really need an `AsyncTask`.

You can do the following:

```
if (compruebaConexion()) {
    // show progress dialog here

    rellenaLista(new CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final ArrayList<Comida> listaComidas) {
            // dismiss dialog
            // handle success
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String msg) {
            // dismiss dialog
            // handle failure
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, you help me to continue with my project. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method `compruebaConexion()`is always false, if you can add to the question the code of this method. I could admit this idea.

Comment: It isn't false, because I check it in debug. This method only check if you can access to Internet, and if you have Wifi or 3G this method always return true

Comment: Change `return completado;`  to `return true;` to test.

Comment: > I tried to delete the if (exito) but the progressDialog dismiss and the list is charged a few seconds later, and it isn't I want.
It's the same that

Answer (score 0):

**Create** a class like that. And check your **internet connection** with it.

```
public class EZInternetConnection {
    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context)
    {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean flag = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
            cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
        return flag;
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
if(EZInternetConnection.isNetworkConnected( context ))   
{
      //internet connection is ok.
      //other codes.

}
else
{
        //no internet.
}
```